# Looping table data from child component not displaying properly in Angular

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 13 and bootstrap 3 and making an app which contains two components: form-component ( *to input details about a user* ) and list-component ( *to display all the data in a table* ). Inside my main app component html, I have a table template that calls my list component for values inside the table body:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <app-contact-list 
      *ngFor="let itemElement of listData; let ind=index" 
      [item]="itemElement" 
      [i]="ind">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">View</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Update</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" (click)="removeItem(itemElement)">Delete</button>
      </app-contact-list>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

inside my list component I wanted to loop these data to the table:

```
<tr>
    <td><span>{{i}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.name}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.email}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.contact}}</span></td>
    <td>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But running the app displays all the data in one cell that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mziwx.jpg

and adding another one gives me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu6M2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table rows have detached from the table DOM element, causing them to render in one cell.

Instead of including the header and rows within the same component HTML, refactor them into respective components `app-contact-header` and `app-contact-list`.

The resulting HTML for `<table>` should include the above components wrapped within the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements as shown:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr app-contact-header></tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr
      app-contact-list
      *ngFor="let itemElement of listData; let ind = index"
      [item]="itemElement"
      [i]="ind"
    ></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The components will need to be declared with an `attribute selector` (not to be confused with [attribute directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)), in order to be injected into the HTML element `<tr>`.

**app-contact-header**

*HTML*

```
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Action</th>
```

*TS*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-contact-header]',
  templateUrl: './contact-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-header.component.css'],
})
export class ContactHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**app-contact-list**

*HTML*

```
<td class="col1">
  <span>{{ i + 1 }}</span>
</td>
<td class="col2">
  <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</td>
<td class="col3">
  <span>{{ item.email }}</span>
</td>
<td class="col4">
  <span>{{ item.contact }}</span>
</td>
<td class="col5">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">View</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Update</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" (click)="removeItem(item)">
    Delete
  </button>
</td>
```

*TS*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-contact-list]',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css'],
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: any;
  @Input() i: number;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ...

  }
}
```

Using HTML `<table>` elements is not responsive. In future consider using `<div>` and `<span>` elements to render columns and rows.